# Open Excel File, Refresh Query and Save C#

Tags: c#, excel-2010

I am trying to open an Excel file, refresh the query behind it and then save and close the file in C#.

I have the following but I am getting errors on the following line first up:

```
        object _missingValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        Application excel = new Application();
        Workbook theWorkbook = excelFile.Workbooks._Open(txtLocation.Text, _missingValue, _missingValue, _missingValue, _missingValue, _missingValue, _missingValue, _missingValue, _missingValue, _missingValue, _missingValue, _missingValue, _missingValue);
        Sheets sheets = (Sheets)theWorkbook.Worksheets;
        theWorkbook.RefreshAll();
        theWorkbook.Save();
        excel.Quit();
```

I have added the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel reference, but still have the issue, what I am missing?

Comment: What errors?  Are they compile errors?  Or run-time exceptions?

Comment: think I have got it now:
            object _missingValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();


Changed to the above and errors are now gone...does this look correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved with the following:

```
object _missingValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            Workbook theWorkbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(txtLocation.Text, _missingValue, _missingValue, _missingValue, _missingValue, _missingValue, _missingValue, _missingValue, _missingValue, _missingValue, _missingValue, _missingValue, _missingValue);
Sheets sheets = (Sheets)theWorkbook.Worksheets;
theWorkbook.Save();
excel.Quit();
return true;
```

Thanks!

Comment: Does it refresh excel ?

Comment: Hi, from what i rememebr it did.  The query was ran as well as the workbook being refresed.